# How can I make html file dynamic with angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an html file and a JS file. The JS file contains some data that I want to present in the html file depending on a clicked link from another html file
html file:

```
                <div class="jumbotron mb-5">
                    {{product.name}}
                </div>
                <div class="jumbotron mb-5">
                    {{product.price}}
                </div>
                <div class="jumbotron mb-5">
                    {{product.description}}
                </div>
```

js file

```
    var app = angular.module('app', [']);

    app.controller('prodCtrl', function ($scope) {
       $scope.courses = [
           {
            id: 1,
            name: 'prod 1',
            description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid ea fugit 
tempore error, tenetur adipisci hic voluptas sapiente distinctio,.',
            price: 100,
            image: 'public/photos/prod1.png'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'prod 2',
            description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.',
            price: 30,
            image: 'public/photos/prod2.png'
        },
      ];
    });
```

in another html page I have the products listed as links and I want to present them in the html page up there depending on the link I clicked

Answer (score 0):

You would pass the param in the route with [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)

It sounds like you're asking for dynamic routing. There are a few questions about this on SO, but to point you in the right direction for what you're doing:

You have to declare your routes in the app config like so:

```
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ui.router'
])
.config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state({
      name: 'product',
      url: '/product/{id}', //{id} or :id will tell it to expect the param
      templateUrl: '/products/index.html',
      controller: 'ProdCtrl'
    });
});
```

Inside your index.html file, make sure you add:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <ui-view></ui-view>
</div>
```

(or where you want the content to appear)

And finally, your controller:

```
.controller('ProdCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {
  //get id from the url and convert it to an int to match data type in courses id
  //may want to consider doing some validation
  $scope.productId = parseInt($stateParams.id);

  var courses = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'prod 1',
      description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.',
      price: 100,
      image: 'public/photos/prod1.png'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'prod 2',
      description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.',
      price: 30,
      image: 'public/photos/prod2.png'
    }
  ];

  //find the matching item by id and set it to scope
  $scope.product = courses.map(function(item) {
    if (item.id === $scope.productId) {
      return item;
    }
  });
});
```

You should now be able to go to `/product/1` and see `prod 1`

Please note this is untested code, but should get you on the right track. I also renamed a couple things for clarity and be more aligned with common practices (e.g. `myApp` and `ProdCtrl`).

If you go through the ui-router documentation, you can also achieve this without using the id in the url and have it pass `params` in the background. This would mean you can only access that page via links in your app and not deep link them.